# Show that $f'(x) = f^2(x)$ and $f(0) = 0$ implies $f$ is the zero function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable be such that $$f'(x)=f^2(x)$$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

My attempt:

Notice that $f'(x)=f^2(x)\geq 0$, thus $f$ is increasing. Since $f(0)=0, f(x)\geq0\; \forall x \geq 0$.
Since $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is continous, therefore given $1> \epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta<1$ such that for $x \in (-\delta,\delta)\implies f(x)<\epsilon<1.$ Take $x=\delta/2$. Then $f(x) = f'(c)\delta/2=f^2(c)\delta/2$. Then $f^2(c) \geq f(x)$. But since $c\in (-\delta,\delta)$, $0\leq f (c)<1 \implies f^2(c) \leq f(c)\implies f(c)\geq f(x)$.
But $c<x$, therefore $f(c)\geq f(x)$ which means $f(c)=f(x)$. Therefore for all $y \in (c,x)$, $f(y)=f(x) \implies f'(y)=f^2(y)=0 \implies f(y)=0$.
Where do I go from here?

Comment: It's not true that $f(x)$ can only be positive or zero. For example, $f(x)=x$ is always increasing and $f(0)=0$

Comment: Do you know the Picard–Lindelöf (aka Cauchy–Lipschitz) theorem?

Comment: @Vasya, I meant that $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x\geq0$. I'm not familiar with the theorem, no.

Comment: You may have a look at the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2535289/72031 which uses elementary calculus and no general theorems from the theory of differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different solution:
$$f'(x)=f^2(x)$$
$f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution. If $f(x)\neq 0$, then we can divide by $f^2(x)$:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}=1$$
Now integrate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x=\int 1 \mathrm{d}x$$
$$-\frac{1}{f(x)}=x+C$$
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=C-x$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{C-x}$$
From this, we have: $f(0)=\frac{1}{C}=0$. But $\nexists C \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\frac{1}{C}=0$, so there can't be a solution in the form of $f(x)=\frac{1}{C-x}$.
Now let's check the trivial solution: $f(x)=0$ is $0$ at $x=0$. It's the only solution that satisfies the initial conditions, so $f(x)=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: All this computation is irrelevant and still leaving out the case when $f(x)$ is zero in many places but not identically zero. All you need to do is either invoke, or prove for this particular equation, the theorem of uniqueness of the solution of the Cauchy problem (none of which is in this answer).

Comment: @YAlexandrov I think you can't make a piece-wise defined function with $f(x)=0$ for many places. If you replace some points in the $f(x)=\frac{1}{C-x}$ with $f(x)=0$, then it will not be continuous at those points (or at the endpoints of the interval of $f(x)=0$). That would imply that $f$ is not differentiable at those points, so it would not solve the differential equation at those points.

Comment: This can be salvaged. If a solution fails to be the zero function, then by continuity, it's non-zero on a neighbourhood of points. The above logic then holds, and produces a function that can never be zero.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, it can be salvaged by adding the proof of uniqueness that a solution for $f'=f^2, f(x_0)=a\neq0$ is ones of those in the whole line.

Comment: @Botond Everybody knows that those are all the solutions and that the case of $f$ being zero in some places and not in others is not possible. The point is that none of the required arguments are given. I would mark an answer like this with a 2 or 3 out of 7.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that proceeds by showing that $(1/f)'=-1$, when we're trying to show that $f=0$, seems unfortunate. It may well be fixable. Here's a somewhat similar solution where division by zero doesn't come anywhere nearby:

Let $A=\{x:f(x)=0\}$. Then $A$ is closed and nonempty, so if we can show that $A$ is open then $A=\Bbb R$, qed.

Suppose that $x_0\in A$. Then we certainly have $1+xf(x)\ne0$ near $x_0$, so near $x_0$ we have $$\left(\frac {f(x)}{1+xf(x)}\right)'=0.$$So $$f(x)=C(1+xf(x))$$near $x_0$. Since $f(x_0)=0$ we must have $C=0$; hence $f=0$ near $x_0$, which is to say that $A$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y(x):\equiv0$ obviously solves the given IVP. By the standard existence and uniqueness theorem, which is applicable in this situation,  this is the only solution in a neighborhood of $x=0$.

If you do not want to make reference to this theorem you have to prove the uniqueness at hoc.

If $x\mapsto y(x)$ $\>(x\geq0)$ is a solution of the given IVP which is not $\equiv0$ define $$\xi:=\inf\,\{x>0\>|\> y(x)\ne0\}\ .$$ We may asssume $\xi=0$. As $y(\cdot)$ is continuous  there is a $\rho\in \>\bigl]0,{1\over2}\bigr]\>$ such that $|y(t)|\leq{1\over2}$ for $0\leq t\leq\rho$. We now have
$$|y(x)|\leq\int_0^\rho|y'(t)|\>dt=\int_0^\rho y^2(t)\>dt\leq \rho M^2\quad(0\leq x\leq\rho)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $M:=\sup_{0\leq t\leq\rho}\bigl|y(t)\bigr|\leq{1\over2}$. Since $(1)$ is true for all $x\in[0,\rho]$ we have
$M\leq {1\over2}M^2$, and this enforces $M=0$, hence in turn the nonexistence of such a $\xi$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a brief solution:

$y=0$ is an obvious solution of $y'=y^2$ that satisfies the initial condition $y(0)=0$.

Ist is easy to prove that the other solutions are $y=\frac{1}{c-x}$ that cannot be $0$.

Comment: This is not a "solution", this is an assertion with no proof.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Right!  it's better now? ( the solution of the differential equation is really easy).

Comment: You've wasted more time typing this comment than you would have writing an actual answer.

Comment: Solving the differential equation is not a solution either, it is actually the uniqueness of the solution what gives the result. Computing $1/(c-x)$ and arguing that they are not zero is completely irrelevant.