# Functional Inequality. Is my approach ok?

Tags: calculus, functional-inequalities

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $$f(x)^2+f'(x)\le 0.$$
> Show that the zero function is the only solution.

I started bwoc assuming that there is a point $x$ such that $f(x)$ is not zero. Hence there is an interval such that $f$ is not zero by continuity. Then I rewrite the equation as $(1/f)'(x)\le 1$.

I would prefer if someone could continue my argument and not find another approach. My question is more of "Is this a step in the right direction?"
A different approach is welocomed too of course if what i said above is not possible.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683895/show-that-fx-f2x-and-f0-0-implies-f-is-the-zero-function, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533837/fx-fx2-prove-fx-0/2535289#2535289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider the following problem: We have some function $g\colon (a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and we know that $g'(x)\le1$ for $x\in(a,b)$, and $g(x_0)=g_0\neq0$ for some $x_0\in(a,b)$.

Now can we conclude that $g(x_0+t) \le g_0+t$? Yes we can!

Suppose that $g(x_0+t)> g_0+t$, then by the mean value theorem, there is some $c\in(x_0,x_0+t)$ such that $g'(c) = \frac{g(x_0+t)-g_0}{t}$. But then $g'(c)>1$, so we know that $g(x_0+t)\le g_0+t$ for all $t$ in the interval $(a-x_0,b-x_0)$.

Now we can get back to our problem: We obtain that $(1/f)(x_0+t)\le (1/f_0)+t$, and thus $f(x_0+t)\ge\frac1{t+1/f_0}$. But then we have a problem as $t\to-1/f_0$, so the only conclusion is that such a $f$ cannot be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A small issue. We cannot know for sure if t can approach -1/f bc x+t has to be in (a,b). You can solve this problem by using the fact that the interval is actually unbounded beacuse f is decreasing.(easy to see that f' is  negative ) hence large or small values of x" will do the job" .( by x i mean x subscrpt 0)

Comment: I don't see how you can conclude that the interval is unbounded to the left (i.e. $a=-\infty$) from the fact that $f$ is decreasing. I don't believe this to be true tbh, and something like this is necessary. The problem occurs when we _assume_ that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, then we have that $f(x_0+t)\ge\frac1{t+1/f_0}$ even for $t\in (-1/f_0,-1/f_0+\varepsilon)$ and thus this $f$ cannot exist.